# CXF Failover Conduit modified on the fly - guarantee same SSL session and client thread safety?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, cxf

I would like to implement CXF's Failover feature for both JAX-WS/RS clients in our application which have to call remote webservices via HTTPS using client certificates. 2 remote servers are in place: Primary + Alternate.

I am a bit lost how to guarantee the same functionality(with the right TLS params/SSL session) after the failover occurs.

**JAX-WS client**

There are 6 ClientServices which `extend AbstractClientServiceImpl` and use the same `PortType wsClient` bean and same basePath of the remote server, however they set their to be invoked service's last uri part with their own `String getEndpointUrl(){ return "X";}` method.

> BasePath: https://remote1.server.com:443/api
>
> Alternate addresses: https://remote2.server.com:443/api

Please take a look at the code - `ClientEndpointAddressInterceptor`. With this interceptor I am able to combine the basePath + lastUriPart and call the proper target endpoint for a particular ClientService - even when failover occurs. E.g:

> target endpoint for ClientService1.class https://remote1.server.com:443/api/service1
>
> target endpoint for ClientService2.class: https://remote1.server.com:443/api/service2

I have been struggling with the right settings/configuration for 2weeks.
If I don't add tlsClientParameters or HttpClientPolicy to the **extensor** like so, then after **having taken place the failover I would not be able** to see any TLS settings for the newly created conduit!

```
// ssl settings
endpointInfo.addExtensor(tlsClientParameters);
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but with this hacky workaround, I could have managed to "provide" the same **tlsClientParams** for the 2 remote calls(primary + alternate remote server address) - client certificate's SAN has both server's DNS names.

Technology: SpringBoot v2.1 + CXF 3.3.0 + Tomcat8.5

```
@Bean
public PortType wsClient(Properties properties,
                                        TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters,
                                        LoggingFeature loggingFeature,
                                        ClientEndpointAddressFeature clientEndpointAddressFeature) {
        return createClient(properties, huTlsClientParameters, loggingFeature, 
    createFailoverFeature(properties.getFailover().getAddresses(), properties.getFailover().getRetryDelay()), 
                clientEndpointAddressFeature);
}

private FailoverFeature createFailoverFeature(String[] alternateAddresses, long failOverRetryDelay) {

    final FailoverFeature failOverFeature = new FailoverFeature();
    final SequentialStrategy strategy = new SequentialStrategy();
    strategy.setAlternateAddresses(Arrays.asList(alternateAddresses));
    strategy.setDelayBetweenRetries(failOverRetryDelay);
    failOverFeature.setStrategy(strategy);
    return failOverFeature;
}

private PortType createClient(Properties properties, TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    final Service service = new Service();
    final PortType client = service.getPortType(features);
    final Client clientProxy = ClientProxy.getClient(client);
    final EndpointInfo endpointInfo = clientProxy.getEndpoint().getEndpointInfo();

    final HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = Optional.ofNullable(endpointInfo.getExtensor(HTTPClientPolicy.class))
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                // if there is no XYFeature, policy has to be initialized at this point
                final HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
                policy.setAccept(HuHttpHeaders.HEADER_ACCEPT_VALUE);
                endpointInfo.addExtensor(policy);
                return policy;
            });
    // timeout settings
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(properties.getConnectionTimeout());
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(properties.getReadTimeout());
    // set content-length by default
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
    // ssl settings
    endpointInfo.addExtensor(tlsClientParameters);
    // set global requestContext
    setRequestContext((BindingProvider) client, properties.getUrl());
    return client;
}


private void setRequestContext(BindingProvider bp, String server) {
    bp.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, server);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(ClientImpl.THREAD_LOCAL_REQUEST_CONTEXT, true);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(Message.SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ENABLED, true);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, true);
}


public class ClientEndpointAddressOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public ClientEndpointAddressOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PREPARE_SEND);
        addBefore(MessageSenderInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        final String previousEndpointAddress = (String) message.get(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);
        final String lastUriPath = (String) message.get("lastUriPath");
        message.put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, previousEndpointAddress + lastUriPath);
   }
}
public abstract class AbstractClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {
        public AbstractClientServiceImpl(PortType PortType) {
            this.portType = portType;
        }
        @Override
        public HttpStatus sendRequest(String xmlData) {
            ...
            final BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) this.portType;
            try {
            // set http header for this particular request          
            // also store bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("lastUriPath", getEndpointUrl()); 
            HttpHeaderUtil.setHttpHeader(getSoapActionUrl(), bindingProvider, getEndpointUrl());
                execute(xmlData, createSoapHeader());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        // last uri part 
        protected abstract String getEndpointUrl();
        // execute is responsible for calling a particular service. e.g: in ClientService1.class portType.callService1(xmlData);
        protected abstract void execute(String xmlData, TransactionHeader transactionHeader);
}
```

**Questions**

**JAX-WS client**

- what happens with the previously set (thread-local-requests,true) setting after the failover occurs? will the following service calls being invoked by the 6 ClientServices class remain thread-safe afterwards?
- I have a requirement that I am supposed to use the SSL session reuse mechanism. IF CXF's failover feature removes the conduit and creates a new one, then how can I apply this again after the failover? Or does Tomcat somehow handles this and no need to bother with this? I am not expert in CXF and I haven't found much info related to SSL session in CXF's site/mailing list.

**JAX-RS client**

Actually the same 2 concerns/questions which are addressed above for JAX-WS client.

The only difference is that RS has 3 client call methods using the same client instance declared as

```
private WebClient webClient(){
   final JAXRSClientFactoryBean clientFactoryBean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();
   clientFactoryBean.setThreadSafe(true);
   final WebClient webClient = clientFactoryBean.createWebClient();
        final ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(webClient);
        config.getRequestContext().put(HTTPConduit.NO_IO_EXCEPTIONS, Boolean.TRUE);
        // ssl settings
    config.getEndpoint().getEndpointInfo().addExtensor(tlsClientParameters);
    return webClient;
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is to use CXF's HTTPConduitConfigurator as detailed here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=49941#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-HowtouseHTTPConduitConfigurer?

```
HTTPConduitConfigurer httpConduitConfigurer = new HTTPConduitConfigurer() {
    public void configure(String name, String address, HTTPConduit c) {
        c.setTlsClientParameters(_tlsParams);
    }
}
bus.setExtension(httpConduitConfigurer, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);
```

This will set the the TLS Client Parameters on all conduits that are created, e.g. when using failover.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It sounds really promising, however we have switched to HW solution(apache proxy) instead of relying on cxf's failover mechanism.
Anyways,I will accept your answer